# ASP NET MVC OnException not being called ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to intercept all exceptions, but the code is never run. I have tried putting this to `GlobalFilters`, and also putting it directly on my method.

My Attributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute 
{
    private ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HandleExceptionAttribute));

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) 
    {
        log.Info("inside on exception"); // this never appears
    }
}
```

My class:

```
public class Tester 
{
    [HandleException]
    public void Except() 
    {
        var asd = 0;
        var qwe = 1 / asd;              
    }
}
```

Dividing by zero give me an exception, my debugger catches it, I continue, but nothing is written into log file.

The logger works. Other logs appear in file. Even if I disable debugging, it doesn't read the log file, so it's not debuggers fault.

Running this on IIS Express. Windows 7.

EDIT:

Moved the thing to controller. Still not working

```
public class UserController : ApiController 
{
    private ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(UserController));

    [HandleException]
    [CheckModelForNull]
    [ValidateModelState]
    public object Post([FromBody]User user) 
    {    
        var asd = 0;
        var qwe = 1 / asd;
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Filter attributes only apply to actions & controllers.  You may be looking for AoP.

Comment: +1 for a well-asked question

Comment: You still don't have the attribute.

Comment: @SLaks see my latest update, mby its because its apicontroller?

Comment: Yes; MVC and Web API are completely different.

Comment: @SLaks so that is the problem, could something similar be done for apicontroller? possibly by `ExceptionFilterAttribute`.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling#exception_filters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ApiControllers do not use `HandleErrorAttribute`

Should better use `ExceptionFilterAttribute`

```
public class NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
       log.error("ERROR",context.Exception);
    }
}
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

Answer (score 4):

As noted in a comment, Filter attributes only apply to actions in controllers. If you want to also capture errors from other classes or something that happens before the code enters an action, you need to overwrite `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log.Info("inside on exception"); 
}
```

Comment: Moved it to controller, still not working. See my edit.

Comment: Have you registered the filter in global.asax (Application_Start method)?

Comment: I have tried, but do not have to register, if I apply it directly on controller endpoint

Comment: Then check that the default HandleErrorAttribute is not registered in your Application_Start method. If it is, it will handle the exception before it gets to your method.